# How to check if a particular character exists within a character array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am using an array within a C# program as follows:

```
char[] x = {'0','1','2'};
string s = "010120301";

foreach (char c in s)
{
    // check if c can be found within s
}
```

How do I check each char c to see if it is found within the character array x?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
if (x.Contains(c))
{
 //// Do Something
}
```

Using .NET 3.0/3.5; you will need a `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Doesn't work with `byte`s, the answer with `Array.IndexOf` ↓ does work.

Answer (score 22):

You could use [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat.aspx) method:

```
if (Array.IndexOf(x, c) > -1)
{
    // The x array contains the character c
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If I understood correctly, you need to check if c is in x. Then:

```
if(x.Contains(c)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "A_123000544654654"; 
string pattern = "[0-9]+";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
```