# Check if a word contains a character not in the alphabet array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string

I have this alphabet array and a word:

```
string Digits = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
Array alphabet = Digits.ToCharArray();
string target = "ABC?0";
```

I want to check if `target` contains a character which is not available in the `alphabet array` and if so, print the character. So in the above example, there are two characters available in `target` and not available in `alphabet` (`"0"` and `"?"`). 
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `ToCharArray`. Simply just use the [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2) method like this:

```
var result = target.Except(Digits).ToArray();
```

And if you still need to use alphabet, change it's type to `char[]`:

```
char[] alphabet = Digits.ToCharArray();
var result = target.Except(alphabet).ToArray();
```

And if you would like to see the result as string, you can use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904289(v=vs.71).aspx) like this:

```
var result = string.Join("", target.Except(Digits));
```

**Just make sure that [`using System.Linq;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) has been already added to your `using` statements.**

Answer (score 1):

```
if(alphabet.Contains(target))
{
  // do some work 
}
```

Also check this link : [How to check if a particular character exists within a character array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818611/how-to-check-if-a-particular-character-exists-within-a-character-array)