# Are there any functions similar to .Contains that will work with "char"?

Tags: c#

So I am creating a hangman-type game in C# and I want the user's input to be recognized as a variable. So I am trying to use this variable(user input) and see if it is found in the word chosen. However, there is no .Contain function that works with "char" variables. Is there any way to make this work? (The part in asterisks is the portion I want to add this code to)

```
using System;

namespace Hangman
{
    class WordChoice
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();

            int numword = rand.Next(2);
            string word = "";
            char[] ltrlist = { ' ' };
            char ltrchce = ' ';

            int strlength = 0;

            **void ltrcheck()
            {
                if 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Great you got a letter");
                }
            }**


            if (numword == 1)
            {
                word = "Shrek";
                strlength = word.Length;
                ltrlist = new char[strlength];
                for (int a = 0; a < strlength; a++)
                {
                    ltrlist[a] = word[a];
                }
            }

           
            if (numword == 2)
            {
                word = "Venom";
                strlength = word.Length;
                ltrlist = new char[strlength];
                for (int a = 0; a < strlength; a++)
                {
                    ltrlist[a] = word[a];
                }
            }

            if (numword == 3)
            {
                word = "Avengers";
                strlength = word.Length;
                ltrlist = new char[strlength];
                for (int a = 0; a < strlength; a++)
                {
                    ltrlist[a] = word[a];
                }
            }

            if (numword == 4)
            {
                word = "Inception";
                strlength = word.Length;
                ltrlist = new char[strlength];
                for (int a = 0; a < strlength; a++)
                {
                    ltrlist[a] = word[a];
                }
            }

            if (numword == 5)
            {
                word = "Batman";
                strlength = word.Length;
                ltrlist = new char[strlength];
                for (int a = 0; a < strlength; a++)
                {
                    ltrlist[a] = word[a];
                }
            }
            string undscr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < strlength; i++)
            {
                undscr = undscr + " _";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(undscr);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Pick a letter");
            string ltrchcestr = Console.ReadLine();
            ltrchce = Convert.ToChar(ltrchcestr);
            ltrcheck();
            
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818611/how-to-check-if-a-particular-character-exists-within-a-character-array) answer your question.

Comment: holup : https://dotnetfiddle.net/F3UDF3 I am confused to what you are asking describing or asking here. `Contains` does take a `char` unless you are using the old and busted .net framework in which case you can use `Contains(someFunkyChar.ToString)`. Can you reclarifying what you are actually trying to do and want.

Comment: @TheGeneral it does? Whenever I try to use the Contain it gives me an error saying "char[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload"

Comment: Pate the line of code you get this error so we can see what you are doing

Comment: Wait nvm @TheGeneral it ended up working I just had to just search the internet for what to add. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: There was no trouble. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can do a function like this

```cs
static bool Contains(IEnumerable < char > items, char letter) 
=> return items?.Any(c => c == letter) == true;
```

or just create a typeExtension, for Project wide use:

```cs
public static class CharExtensions {
    public static bool Contains(this IEnumerable<char> items, char letter ){
        return items?.Any(c => c == letter) == true;
    }
}
```

this test will now work:

```cs
var chars = new []{'a','b','c'};
Console.WriteLine(chars.Contains('m'));
Console.WriteLine(chars.Contains('b'));
```